# Raspberry pi a+ vnc connection refused

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi a+ that I am trying to control via RealVNC on my laptop. It worked fine before but now I can only establish a connection via SSH as the connection gets refused. It was working fine before. Software on the Pi is up to date.

Comment: This is a question for stackoverflow

Comment: Instead of just randomly moving to what now amounts to three options, just VTC and let OP decide.

Comment: Connection refused suggests either the connection is being blocked (by a firewall configuration maybe) or that the server isn't running for some reason. There is an issue where the RealVNC server app won't start if there is no keyboard or mouse plugged into the pi. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=230779&p=1413648#p1413648